# How can I replace lines in a text file with lines from another file based on matching pattern?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I want to replace some lines in a file with lines from another file based on matching a pattern.
I want to replace every line that begin with "rolOccupant" after finding 
"# SBD_ING_USER" to the empty line with content from file x

**File x**

```
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80
```

**Input file**

```
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid7
roleOccupant: uid67

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER: 
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

**OUTPUT file**

```
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER: 
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

Answer (score 2):

**awk** one-liner

```
 awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{a=$0;next} /SDB_ING_USER/{sub(/roleOccupant.*/,""); $0=$0 a} 1' fileX file
```

`-v RS=` to set empty line as the Record Separator

`FNR==NR{a=a$0; next}` : This will store your `File X` contents in variable `a`

`/# SDB_ING_USER/ {gsub(/roleOccupant.*/,a ORS)}` : While iterating over your `Input file` if record contains `# SDB_ING_USER` then substitute all lines starting from `roleOccupant` to end of record with `a ORS` in other words `a "\n"`

**Output:**

```
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER:
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

**One-liner:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{r=(r!=""?r RS:"")$0;next}/# SDB_ING_USER/{u=1}u && /^roleOccupant:/{next}u && !NF{print r; u=""}1;END{if(u)print r}' file1 file2
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk '
     FNR==NR{
          r=(r!=""?r RS:"")$0;
          next
     }
     /# SDB_ING_USER/{
          u=1
     }
     u && /^roleOccupant:/{
         next
    }
    u && !NF{
         print r; 
         u=""
    }1
    END{
         if(u)print r
    }
    ' file1 file2
```

**Explanation:**

- `FNR==NR{r=(r!=""?r RS:"")$0;next}` This block we read only `file1` and save file1 rows in variable `r`, separated by record separator `RS`, `FNR==NR` will be true, only when `awk` reads first file.
- `/# SDB_ING_USER/{u=1}` if line from `file2`, contains regexp in `/..../` then, set variable `u=1`
- `u && /^roleOccupant:/{next}` if variable `u` is set, and line starts with `roleOccupant`, skip such line, and go to next record, from `file2`
- `u && !NF{print r; u=""}` if variable `u` is set, and `!NF`, meaning empty line (`NF` gives no of fields in record, `NF=0` means blank line, `!0` is `1`, which is true state), then print variable `r`, and nullify variable `u`
- `}1` 1 at the end does default operation, thats print current record/row/line, in current context, this default operation takes only if record not skipped in above, statements.

**file1:**

```
$ cat file1
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80
```

**file2:**

```
$ cat file2
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid7
roleOccupant: uid67

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER: 
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{r=(r!=""?r RS:"")$0;next}/# SDB_ING_USER/{u=1}u && /^roleOccupant:/{next}u && !NF{print r; u=""}1;END{if(u)print r}' file1 file2
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER: 
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the input file is `sdb.txt` and file x is `x.txt`, I use a sed command file `cmd.sed` to do this:

`sed -f cmd.sed sdb.txt`

`sed.cmd` :

```
# Within the section from SDB_ING_USER to a blank line
/SDB_ING_USER/,/^$/{
    # Delete roleOccupant lines
    /roleOccupant/d
    # At the blank line
    /^$/{
        # Read x.txt into the output stream
        r x.txt
        # Append a blank line to the output stream
        a
        # Delete the blank line from the input stream
        # (Prevents a blank line before the x.txt content)
        d
    }
}
```

This is done with a sed command file rather than as a single line sed command bcause the sed `r` and `a` commands require a newline, <s>so they are painful to try to use in a one-liner.</s> (See EDIT below regarding newlines and `-e`)

Output:

```
$ sed -f cmd.sed sdb.txt
# SDB_ING_USER
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_ING_USER
description: SDB Ing User Role
roleOccupant: uid1
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid45
roleOccupant: uid80

# SDB_REGISTERY_USER: 
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: SDB_REGISTRY_USER
description: SDB Registry Admin Role
roleOccupant: uid2
roleOccupant: uid34
roleOccupant: uid15
```

EDIT.  Looked at potong's use of `e cat` which allows reading the x.txt file into the pattern space (rather than output stream) AND realized that at the command line you can just use multiple `-e` arguments to get effective line breaks in one-liner sed commands.

So here's a new one-liner:

`sed -e '/SDB_ING_USER/,/^$/{' -e '/roleOccupant/d' -e '/^$/e cat x.txt' -e '}'  sdb.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/SDB_ING_USER/,/^\s*$/!b;/roleOccupant/d;/^\s*$/e cat x' file
```

Focus on the lines between `SDB_ING_USER` and the next empty line. Delete any lines containing the string `roleOccupant` and insert file `x` before the empty line.